# how to dynamically append a list to a master URL

Tags: python, pandas, urllib

For the time being, let's say this is the content I scraped:

```
[<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Taipei for Digital Nomads">Taipei</a>,  
<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Lisbon for Digital Nomads">Lisbon</a>,  
<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Buenos Aires for Digital Nomads">Buenos Aires</a>,  
<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Budapest for Digital Nomads">Budapest</a>]
```

I want to create a list of urls that's appending each of the city to the master url:
`https://nomadlist.com`

and I want to make it like on the output:

```
https://nomadlist.com/taipei,
https://nomadlist.com/lisbon,
https://nomadlist.com/buenos-aires,
https://nomadlist.com/budapest
```

Can anyone help me with the code? What I am struggling is how to dynamically pull the city info, and append them one by one

Comment: is it what list of strings the scrapped data?

Comment: Use Beautiful Soup to parse the HTML, and get the text of the anchors. Then just concatenate it to the mater URL.

Comment: @Kai, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

@Kai Jinglebell Cheng is this what you are looking for?

```
nomad_list = ['<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Taipei for Digital Nomads">Taipei</a>',  
'<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Lisbon for Digital Nomads">Lisbon</a>',  
'<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Buenos Aires for Digital Nomads">Buenos Aires</a>',  
'<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Budapest for Digital Nomads">Budapest</a>']

base_link = 'https://nomadlist.com/'
for nomad in nomad_list:
    city = nomad.split(">")[1].split("<")[0].replace(' ', '-').lower()
    full_link = f'{base_link}{city}'
    print(full_link)
```

---

### New Answer after updated question below

```
nomad_str = '''["<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Taipei for Digital Nomads">Taipei</a>",  
"<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Lisbon for Digital Nomads">Lisbon</a>",  
"<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Buenos Aires for Digital Nomads">Buenos Aires</a>",  
"<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Budapest for Digital Nomads">Budapest</a>"]'''
nomad_str=nomad_str.replace('"<a', "'<a")
nomad_str=nomad_str.replace('a>"', "a>''")
nomad_str=nomad_str.replace("[\'", '')
nomad_str=nomad_str.replace("'\']", '')
nomad_list = nomad_str.split(',')
base_link = 'https://nomadlist.com/'
for nomad in nomad_list:
    city = nomad.split(">")[1].split("<")[0].replace(' ', '-').lower()
    full_link = f'{base_link}{city}'
    print(full_link)
```

Comment: Thank you! but my list does not contain single quote, do you know how do I add them before proceeding your quote?

Comment: @KaiJinglebellCheng if you scraped the data, then it shouldn't be in the format in your question right? Otherwise, it's impossible to assign it as a list. If you needed to manipulation of hte data on the list first then you could put quotes around the bracket and begin to manipulate the data and transform it from there, but I don't see the point of the exercise. If you scraped the data, I don't think it should show up like that? But, I could be wrong. I changed my answer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, use bs4 python package.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Taipei for Digital Nomads">Taipei</a>',
        '<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Lisbon for Digital Nomads">Lisbon</a>',
        '<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Buenos Aires for Digital Nomads">Buenos Aires</a>',  
        '<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Budapest for Digital Nomads">Budapest</a>'
        ]

uri = 'https://nomadlist.com/'
uri_list = []

uri_list = [uri + BeautifulSoup(i, features="lxml").find('a').string.replace(' ', '-').lower() for i in urls]
print(uri_list)
```

output:

```
['https://nomadlist.com/taipei', 'https://nomadlist.com/lisbon', 'https://nomadlist.com/buenos-aires', 'https://nomadlist.com/budapest']
```

Comment: Thank you! but my list does not contain single quote, do you know how do I add them before proceeding your quote?

Answer (score 0):

If you used BeautifulSoup, I think it's better to process the data straight from BeautifulSoup than convert first to a list like so :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = '''
<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Taipei for Digital Nomads">Taipei</a>
<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Lisbon for Digital Nomads">Lisbon</a>  
<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Buenos Aires for Digital Nomads">Buenos Aires</a>
<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Budapest for Digital Nomads">Budapest</a>
'''

base_url = 'https://nomadlist.com'

data = BeautifulSoup(html_string,"html.parser")

filtered_data = data.find_all("a")

url_list = [base_url+"/"+item.get_text().replace(" ","-").lower() for item in filtered_data]

print(url_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript you can do something like this. You can use the same logic & change the syntax to python.

```js
var baseURL = 'https://nomadlist.com/';
var urls = [];

var strings = ['<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Taipei for Digital Nomads">Taipei</a>','<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Lisbon for Digital Nomads">Lisbon</a>',  
'<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Buenos Aires for Digital Nomads">Buenos Aires</a>',  
'<a href="" itemprop="url" title="Budapest for Digital Nomads">Budapest</a>'];

strings.forEach( x => {
  urls.push(baseURL + x.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').toLowerCase().replace(" ","-"));
});

console.log(urls);
```

Comment: I think he's asking for python solutions.!

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya I wrote that on top